# Arm Gcc Weak Alias Redefinition

Tags: c, gcc, microcontroller

I wanted to create weak alias for several functions so that I can declare it in a header file but then define it later on in different files. For some reason I still get a redefinition error from gcc.

Ideally for functions that don't have implementations I would like for it to default back on the alias.

I have tried removing alias("Default_Handler") and it seems to compile but it sort of destroys my intention for this application I am trying to write.

vector_table.h

```c
void __attribute__((noreturn))  Default_Handler (void);                                                  
void NMI_Handler(void) __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
```

startup.c

```c
#include "vector_table.h"

void Default_Handler(void){                                                                                                                                
    for(;;);                                                                      
}                                                                               

void NMI_Handler(void){                                                         
    for(;;);                                                                      
}
```

```sh
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -Wall -Wno-unused -Wextra -pedantic -H -g3 -gdwarf-2 -O0 -std=c90 -ffreestanding -c startup.c

startup.c:93:6: error: redefinition of 'NMI_Handler'
 void NMI_Handler(void){
      ^
In file included from startup.c:3:0:
vector_table.h:17:6: note: previous definition of 'NMI_Handler' was here
 void NMI_Handler(void) __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: Don't put `__weak__` nor `__alias__` in `.h` file. Put `__weak__` and `__alias__` in `.c` file.

Weak symbols theoretically work like this:

- There is one `.o` file with `__weak__` symbol.
- There is another `.o` file with a normal symbol.
- Linker sees both symbols and picks the non-weak symbol.

The `.o` object files are generated from `.c` files. The definition of the symbol inside `.c` should be weak.

Attributes applied to declaration are applied to definitions that see it. Doing `__weak__` in a header in a declaration marks **all** definitions that see that declaration of this symbol as `__weak__`.

The `alias` works as if you would do:

```
static inline void NMI_Handler(void) {
     Default_Handler();
}
```

It works as-if the same, but without the branch (and less typing). And anyway, because `alias` creates the symbol, it acts as a definition - it belongs in a `.c` file also. This is the reason you get multiple definition error - the `__alias__`  defines the symbol `NMI_Handler` and you later define `void NMI_Handler(void) {}` again.

What you want to do I think is this:

```
// vector_table.h
void __attribute__((noreturn))  Default_Handler (void);                                                  
void NMI_Handler(void);

// startup.c     
void Default_Handler(void){                                                                                                                                
    for(;;);                                                                      
}   

__attribute__((__weak__, __alias__("NMI_Handler")))
void  NMI_Handler(void);
```

Which is the same as the example use as explained in [gcc documentation about function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes). The documentation states, that the another symbol that is aliased has to be defined in the same transaction unit (read as: in the same `.c` file).

Remember that declaring a symbol as weak doesn't mean that linker will peak the strong symbol - when compiling with static libraries sometimes strange thing happen. Compile with objects only or use `-Wl,-start-group` linker options. I think the [infocenter.arm](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0205g/CIACBCDA.html) has best explanation about that.

Comment: Would you recommend putting the actual vector table in the startup.c file as well then or could i still put the vector table in vector_table.h?

Comment: "actual vector table"? What is that? I think I only worked with stm32 where I had a assembly file with a section that specified what interrupt goes to what function (or something like that).

Comment: What I mean by "actual vector table" is an array of function pointers:
 `void (* const vector_table[])(void) __attribute__((section(".isr_vector"))) = {
Default_Handler,
NMI_Handler
};`

Comment: What you've have showed it's clearly a definition, so it goes in a `.c` file by convention. I believe it would be a good time to read about what is a definition, what is a declaration, what is a translation unit, what goes into a header, what goes into a source file, etc.. Och, that's cool, it looks like what mbed has.

Comment: I know the assembly file you are refering to: [link](https://github.com/cdmeister/Embedded/blob/bare_metal/system/startup/startup_stm32f407xx.s).  This is my attempt to break it out into C instead of assembly and move some components into individual files. I appreciate the help.

Comment: If we were to go with assembly file that provided that weak alias and vector table, how is it we are still able to provide a strong definitions in other files with a .c extension?

Comment: ? This is exactly what weak symbols are for - to provide weak symbol in one file and provide a strong symbol in other file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201899/discussion-between-moeiz-riaz-and-kamil-cuk).